# Javascript, Display image based on browser.

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write javascript to display a choice of two images based on a users browser.
I want it to check is the user running Firefox, if not display a different image.
I'm not having much luck trying to do this on my own and was hoping someone could point me in the right direction.
Here's what I have so far.

```
if (var x = "Firefox") {
document.write('<img border="0" src="1.jpg" />');

} else {
document.write('<a href="myfile.htm"><img border="0" src="2.jpg" /></a>');
}

function myFunction()
{
var x = "Browser Name: " + navigator.appName;
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=x;
}
</script>
```

Comment: First problem: `if (var x = "Firefox")`

Comment: Why exactly are you doing this? It's generally considered better and less fragile to do feature detection rather than browser detection. An easy way to do feature detection is with Modernizr. An example of why browser detection is fragile is IE11's user agent string - `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko`. Also, remember that a user can always override the user agent string. Basically, don't try to give users different experiences based on their browser. Instead, just determine what their browser is capable of.

Comment: It's part of a school project, this part has to be done in javascript.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. If that's what you have to do for the grade then go ahead and do it. I would highly recommend showing your teacher this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh273397(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I used this:

```
if(navigator.userAgent.match(/Firefox/)) {
    // actions
}
```